# Create multiple alerts for multiple lists at once

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, alert

Creating an alert to be notified of changes in a list is a 5-6 clicks process in Sharepoint 2013. Our users need to subscribe to 30-40 lists so is there a way to do it "all at once" or somehow reduce the number of steps required to subscribe to all lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no easy way to reduce the number of clicks.  What you need, you have to write a utility for end user to sign up for multiple lists.

Below code snipt will create alerts for one list, now from here you have to write your logic and add multiple lists...may be write all lists url in the Notepad or etc...

```
    If you want the alert to be added to list,
var list = collabWeb.Lists["ListName"];


If you want the alert to be added to list item, get the List Item ID or SPListItem


using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://URLHere"))
{ 
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
       var newAlert = web.Alerts.Add();
       newAlert.Title = "Test Alert"; 
       newAlert.AlwaysNotify = 0/1; (Boolean)
       newAlert.User = "Domain\User";
       newAlert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate | 
                                                      SPAlertFrequency.Daily | 
                                                      SPAlertFrequency.Weekly;
   //Here comes the 2 properties where I had trouble
   //To Set the newAlert.EventType follow this


   newAlert.Properties["eventtypeindex"] = "0"; // 0 - All, 1 - Add, 2 - Modify, 3 - Delete, 
                                                                               // 4 - Discussion
   //To Set the newAlert.Filter follow this

   // These values vary from list to list i.e. different for custom list, discussion forum, Tasks, 
   // Announcements etc. Go through the filter options first and get the index of the items in 
   // Filter starting from 0 and set the required option in code.


   newAlert.Properties["filterindex"] = "2";                


   //If you are setting the alert on List Item and you know the SPListItem
   newAlert.Item = listItem;


  {or) //You can never set both of these together. So pick either one of them


   //If you are setting the alert on complete list use
   newAlert.List = list;


   newAlert.Update(false); //set it to false if you donot want the notification to be sent right 
                                            //away else true 
}
```

}

http://preethichappidi.blogspot.com/2012/05/programmatically-adding-alerts-to.html

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/programmatically-creating-alerts-in-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 0):

Someone is going to have to do 5-6 clicks.  :)

Set up a workflow which initiates an email when an item is created/changed for the list.

Have it point to a disto list/mailbox (easy) or manually add the names (harder).

This can be as simple as a one line workflow or more complicated.

This article walks you through basic steps.

http://sp2013.pro/2013/02/creating-spd-2013-workflows-part-13-extremely-simple-workflow-and-default-task-form/